# Disable warning/error beep when changing focus

Tags: c#

Whenever I change the focus from one textbox to another it plays an irritating warning/error beep.

Example:

```
public void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)  
        textBox2.Focus();  
}
```

whenever I press **Enter** it changes the focus to textBox2 and gives the warning beep.

Any help to disable this would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to add `e.Handled = true` to the event handler:

```
public void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        textBox2.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

A side node: you should be able to use the `KeyCode` instead of the `KeyChar` property, avoiding the cast:

```
public void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        textBox2.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

e.SuppressKeyPress = true;